# What is the meaning of 'simple zeroes' in this context?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

The author claims:

An irreducible polynomial is separable if its zeroes in its splitting field are simple. It turns out that over $\Bbb{C}$ this property is automatic.

---

Isn't a 'simple zero' one that is not repeated? Though I don't think the author is using this definition. Is there any other interpretation that matches the context of the sentence?

Comment: Why do you think not?

Comment: Note the assumption of an *irreducible* polynomial. Reducible polynomials obviously may not necessarily be separable.

Comment: @Dustan Levenstein. Irreducible....of course. Thank you.

Comment: Let $p$ an odd prime and $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$ the quotient field of the polynomial ring $\mathbb{F}_p[t]$ and $P(x) = x^p - t^p  \in \mathbb{F}_p(t^p)[x]$. Then $P$ is non-separable. This is so because in characteristic $p$ : $(x-t)^p = x^p+(-t)^p$ and $P$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_p(t^p)$. In other words $\zeta_p$ doesn't exist in characteristic $p$ which makes some polynomials non-separable, and in characteristic $0$ there is no such problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"In mathematics, a polynomial $P(X)$ over a given field $K$ is *separable* if its roots are distinct in an algebraic closure of $K$, that is, the number of distinct roots is equal to the degree of the polynomial." (from [Wikipedia: Separable polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_polynomial))

It appears from this alternate definition that your first interpretation was correct, and that non-repeated zeros are exactly the kind that we're talking about.